# How to deploy/host react native apps in web and viewed only in mobile view even when opening it in desktop

Tags: android, react-native

Unlike react native for web. I was looking if there are ways to host apps on web only in mobile view, no matter the devices you use to access it on web. I'm a junior react native dev and was thinking to showcase my projects differently to my prospective employers. Thank you in advance!

I have tried searching for viewport, tried different ways of googling and youtube.